# How to call a macro within a macro in Stata

Tags: macros, stata

Here is my code:

```
local father_yes "c2[_n+`i']==1"

foreach i of numlist 1/15{
   replace withfa=1 if "`hz_father_yes'"
}
```

Then I found the local macro `` `i' `` of the loop cannot be identified within the father_yes macro I defined. How can I get it identified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but it seems as if the issue is that you are referencing `` `i' `` before you define it.

Besides that you are probably also getting errors as you are using `` `hz_father_yes' `` as a string by putting it inside string quotes `""`.

Would this work:

```
foreach i of numlist 1/15 {
  local father_yes "c2[_n+`i']==1"
  replace withfa=1 if `hz_father_yes'
}
```

But then I think it would be cleaner to do:

```
foreach i of numlist 1/15 {
  replace withfa = 1 if c2[_n+`i']==1
}
```

Let us know what error you get if this does not work for you.

Comment: This is close to mine, drafted at essentially the same time,  but note the extra point about `hz_father_yes`.

Comment: I missed that, but unless a good reason to keep it, it seems to me as if the code should be simplified

Comment: I agree; no local macros are needed at all except the macro that indexes the loop.

Comment: yes exactly right! I need to firstly define `i'.  The part on c2[_n+`i']  is actually way more complicated (I simplified it for convinience), that is why I prefer to define a macro for clarity.

Comment: Based on what you show us, I still consider use of a local macro to confuse code, not clarify it. The fact that you got confused about how to use local macros at all seems pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that when you define the first macro, local macro `i` is not defined, so the definition is then

```
local father_yes "c2[_n+]==1"
```

which is not illegal at that point, but is not what you want.

`foreach` is legal there, but I would rewrite this as

```
forval i = 1/15 {
    replace withfa = 1 if c2[_n + `i'] == 1 

}
```

noting that in your code

1. the local macro `father_yes` would be illegal if used as defined, and even if corrected remains unnecessary
2. the local macro `hz_father_yes` is not defined
3. comparisons of the form `if "`string`"` are illegal, as strings are not regarded as true or false.